# How to register a device in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

i need to register a new device in linux but i noticed that in kernel 2.6.34 function `device_register` is not exported...Which could be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should rather use `register_blkdev` or `register_chrdev`, depending on the device type.

Comment: I don't have neither a block device or a character device:(I have to find a way to recognize a switch Marvell connected to microprocessor by a MII/MDIO bus. I found that the bus is managed as open-firmware bus, but cycling on bus' devices i can't find it. I can find only one device `e0102120.mdio` that should be the mdio controller . looking at `/sys/devices/e0100000.qe/e0102120.mdio/` i can found two devs (i hope) `mdio@e0102120:11` and `mdio@e0102120:12`. How can i access these devices?

Comment: @MirkoBanchi Then your question is slightly unclear (btw, I've seen your other question where you ask about MII interface, it's also a bit unclear). What is your goal? My understanding is that you have some MPC8306 - why do you need to control MII in first place? Please provide more background.

Answer (score 1):

In linux-2.6.32.28/drivers/base

```
core.c:EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(device_register);
```

ANd for 2.6.38 is also in the same file - which make me conclude in 2.6.34 it should be in the same file as well?

But if u are talking about mdio the following are the symbols found (via nm vmlinux):

```
ffffffff81b66fae t fixed_mdio_bus_exit
ffffffff81af4468 t fixed_mdio_bus_init
ffffffff813977f0 t fixed_mdio_read
ffffffff81397610 t fixed_mdio_write
ffffffff81a68760 d mdio_bus_class
ffffffff813971b0 T mdio_bus_exit
ffffffff81af4425 T mdio_bus_init
ffffffff81396fd0 t mdio_bus_match
ffffffff81a687e0 d mdio_bus_pm_ops
ffffffff81396ff0 t mdio_bus_restore
ffffffff81397050 t mdio_bus_resume
ffffffff81397100 t mdio_bus_suspend
ffffffff81a686e0 D mdio_bus_type
ffffffff813975d0 T mdiobus_alloc
ffffffff81397380 T mdiobus_free
ffffffff813972a0 T mdiobus_read
ffffffff81397430 T mdiobus_register
ffffffff813971e0 t mdiobus_release
ffffffff81397330 T mdiobus_scan
ffffffff813973c0 T mdiobus_unregister
ffffffff81397210 T mdiobus_write
```

and for mii:

```
ffffffff81507a20 T dsa_slave_mii_bus_init
ffffffff81395b60 T phy_mii_ioctl
```

And for EXPORT_SYMBOL declaration:

```
./drivers/of/of_mdio.c:
EXPORT_SYMBOL(of_mdiobus_register);

./drivers/net/phy/mdio-bitbang.c:
EXPORT_SYMBOL(alloc_mdio_bitbang);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(free_mdio_bitbang);

./drivers/net/phy/mdio_bus.c:
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdiobus_alloc);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdiobus_register);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdiobus_unregister);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdiobus_free);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdiobus_scan);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdiobus_read);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdiobus_write);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdio_bus_type);

./drivers/net/phy/mdio-octeon.c:
EXPORT_SYMBOL(octeon_mdiobus_force_mod_depencency);

./drivers/net/fec_mpc52xx_phy.c:
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(mpc52xx_fec_mdio_driver);

./drivers/net/mdio.c:
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdio45_probe);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdio_set_flag);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdio45_links_ok);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdio45_nway_restart);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdio45_ethtool_gset_npage);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdio45_ethtool_spauseparam_an);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mdio_mii_ioctl);

./drivers/net/fsl_pq_mdio.c:
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(fsl_pq_mdio_bus_name);

./drivers/s390/net/qeth_core_main.c:
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(qeth_mdio_read);
```

Not sure if these help you?

Your similar question posted at:

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/178782-how-control-switch-marvel-88e6097-mdio-bus-mpc8306-processor.html

is much clearer.   More info on MPC8306 (hardware, linux-kernel specific etc) can be found here:

http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MPC830xKIT

http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MPC8306

and according to this:

http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/21828/

the patch for MDIO is elaborated and explained somewhat.

And here:

http://www.mail-archive.com/eldk@lists.denx.de/msg00235.html

is also mentioned that the ELDK for MPC8306 need no changes for support.

Anyway hardware info can be found here:

http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MPC8306&fpsp=1&tab=Documentation_Tab

Comment: Thank you very much Peter!I already found and looked at that functions...Maybe i can't for now undestand completely how linux manages busses and devices...I don't really know which functions i've to use and how:(

Comment: at this page:

http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MPC8306&fpsp=1&tab=Design_Tools_Tab

u can find the LinuxBSP and device drivers source codes for MPC8306.

THanks.

Comment: Yes, that question on LinuxForums was posted by me :).Thank you Peter for all links!

Answer (score 0):

O'Reillys great book about Device Drivers are freely available here [O'reilly](http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxdrive3/book/index.csp). A bit outdated but a good reference. Not what you asked for, but a good reference...