# Kernel function to register device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I was trying to understand inner workings of Linux kernel. I have trouble understanding how devices get registered. I am guessing all of the device data gets passed to one function at some point to get registered whether it be platform device, devicetree, char and block devices, plug and play device, etc.

1. What is the internal function?
2. Would it be visible in the devtmpfs, devfs, sysfs?
3. How buses (virtual / physical) play role in it. Is it necessary to register to a specific bus?

I looked at [How to register a device in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108554/how-to-register-a-device-in-linux) but I am not sure suggestions are particularly low level and all devices go through them at some point (platform devices have a separate high level function).

Comment: "I am guessing all of the device data gets passed to one function at some point to get registered whether it be platform device, devicetree, char and block devices, plug and play device, etc." - No, your guess is wrong. These registrations doesn't have a common "internal function". Such registrations use "kobject" mechanism, but they operate on kobjects from different trees. In you wonder how a particular function works, then you could look into the code of that function.

Comment: Registering a device to kernel whether it be a device on discoverable bus or platform device or virtual device results in one action -- getting that device recognized by kernel. Doesn't it mean devices get added in a similar pattern? What are the lowest categories of devices from kernels perspective? Sysfs only shows devices registered through sysfs. Isn't it possible a device gets _visible_ to kernel but hidden from sysfs before getting registered to some subsystem or something?

Comment: "Doesn't it mean devices get added in a similar pattern?" - You could treat "kobject" mechanism as a "pattern", but it is not a "central repository of devices". Both in the question post and in the comment you ask **too many questions** about different aspects of the devices in the Linux kernel. But this topic is too large for being answered on Stack Overflow. I would suggest you to read some books/articles/documentation on that topic. You could read e.g. about kobjects, about registration of devices of particular type, etc.

Comment: Thanks I get it. I am a newbie so I myself was unsure what to ask for. I was trying to think of these different functions as wrappers around something common. Kobjects appear to be that common thing. One last question, what other topics/keywords would  you suggest to help me answer my questions?